# Math and Origami

Tags: field-theory, definition, origami

I am working on a project for class about the mathematics behind origami and write now I am looking into what is and is not constructible. I've gotten to the definition of origami constructible points which says the following:

The set of origami constructible points $P_0$ is defined as:
$P_0=\{P|(0,0),(0,1) \in P$ and $P$ is closed under origami constructions$\}$.

I am having a very difficult time understanding what this is saying and it is a key point in my project. If anyone could explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578683/mathematics-and-origami

Answer (score 3):

It seems you should actually start with $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ as you have all four corners of the paper.  Then you define what constructions are allowed.  I imagine that folding on a line through any points you already have is one.  Another would be bringing together two pairs of points that are the same distance apart.  There may be more operations permitted.  The points generated are from the intersections of fold lines and the edges of the paper.  After you generate some points, you look what constructions are available using those points.

For an example, you  can fold the paper in half horizontally, making a crease along $(0,\frac 12)$ to $(1,\frac 12)$  This generates the points $(0,\frac 12)$ and $(1,\frac 12)$ where the  crease hits the edges.  Now folding the bottom to that crease gets you $(0,\frac 14)$ and $(1,\frac 14)$ and it should be clear you can get all the dyadic fractions this way.  Then you can fold $(1,0)$ to $(\frac 12,1)$ making a diagonal line and crossing many of the horizontal and vertical lines you already have.  You imagine keeping this up as much as necessary until you can't get any new points.  The set $P_0$ the set of points you can generate.  It will be countably infinite, but every point in it can be reached with a finite number of operations.

Comment: thank you very much! This clarifies things greatly for me. This is exactly what I was looking for in order to explain the mathematical definition.

Comment: As a one-time origamist, it seems to me that you can construct $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$, so you don't need them in your initial set. Specifically: Let $A=(0,0), B=(0,1)$. We can construct line $AB$; and from the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, we can construct lines through $A$ and $B$ perpendicular to $AB$. Now from $AB$ and the line through $A$ perpendicular to $AB$, we can make a $45^{\circ}$ fold through $A$, which intersects the perpendicluar through $B$ at $(1,1)$. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are asking about Definition 3.3 on page 10 of [*The Mathematics of Origami*](http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Sheri.pdf) by Sheri Lin, which cites a *Math Monthly* paper by Auckly and Cleveland, a version of which is available [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407174.pdf).  The Lin paper omits a symbol:  It should read

$$P_0 = \cap\{P | (0,0),(0,1)\in P \text{ and $P$ is closed under origami constructions}\}$$

What's missing is the intersection symbol.  Does this clarify matters?

**Added later**:  The "$\cap$" in effect means that you're defining the *smallest* set containing two starting points that's closed under origami constructions.  (A tacit lemma is that the intersection of two "closed" sets is again "closed.")  You need two points to get a nontrivial smallest set.  The intersection is well defined because at the very least you have the *entire* set of points in the plane as a set $P$ that is closed under origami constructions.

One might alternatively define the constructible points as the *union* of the finite sets that are produced by applying origami procedures to obtain "new" points out of "existing" ones, but to do so one would have to keep track of lines along the way as well.  The paper(s) chose a cleaner approach in which they define a notion of *origami pair* (any set of points and lines satisfying their origami axioms), followed by a definition of a point set being closed under origami construction (namely, being part of an origami pair), followed by the definition of "the" set of constructible points.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes that is what I am referring to but it was just a type that I forgot the intersection symbol. I am unclear on what that definition is telling me still.

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: I am reading The Mathematics of Origami (the one you referred to in the answer). Definition 3.3 is followed by the definition of the set of origami numbers. But I am not sure how to differentiate these two definitions?

Comment: @user72195, the origami constructible points, $P$, is a set of points in the plane.  The origami numbers, $F_0$, is a set of numbers, initially defined as the set of distances between pairs of constructible points, but quickly shown to be identical with the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of constructible points (and then shown to be a field closed under the mapping that sends $x$ to $\sqrt{1+x^2}$).  So basically you need to define origami constructible points in order to define origami numbers.